# Git flow question, merging to master and develop

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-flow

I am currently using git flow with sourcetree. Work is agreed for the sprint and I create branches off develop to commit code into. I merge the feature branches into develop, then at the end of sprint I merge to master and code goes into production.

This works fine, however, if a fix needs pushing to master or if other work is bought into sprint, commits need to be sorted and cherry picked into master which can get very messy.

This can cause lots of blockers, as work needs to be pushed to master, tested and signed off before other work can be committed into develop.

Is there a way to safely bring in new work and commit to develop?

Comment: _This can cause lots of blockers, as work needs to be pushed to master, tested and signed off before other work can be committed into develop_, I don't believe this is true. You can merge your hot-fixes into master while still merging features into develop. After each hot-fix is merged into master then you should also merge master into develop.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I merge the feature branches into develop, then at the end of sprint I merge to master and code goes into production.

You can certainly do that if you wish, but typically in Git Flow you don't merge `develop` *directly* into `master` because of the exact problems you are running into:

> This can cause lots of blockers, as work needs to be pushed to master, tested and signed off before other work can be committed into develop.

The way Git Flow avoids these problems is with `release` and `hotfix` branches. ([See diagram](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/#diagram) for details.)

You simply create a `release` branch for testing prior to releasing, and therefore work on `develop` never has to stop. (Note you don't have to create a `release` branch from the tip of `develop`; you can use any prior commit that you wish to branch from.)

When you need to do a hotfix into production, you create a `hotfix` branch off of `master`.

After your code is merged into `master` from either `release` or `hotfix` branch, then you would also merge `master` back into `develop`. (Or you could merge the `release` and `hotfix` branches back to `develop` just prior to merging them into `master`, but merging `master` back after is IMHO slightly cleaner and easier to manage.)

**Side note:** the `release` and `hotfix` branches are usually well-defined, however, since you are currently working without them, you still *can* work without them but with a few slight tweaks. For example, suppose you take your current `develop` and start testing a build somewhere, and then you like it and want to release it into production. You actually have a `release` branch, but it isn't named. It's just the commit ID of what you tested. When you release, simply merge that commit ID from `develop` into `master` instead of `develop` which might be ahead of that commit. That way you won't also merge in any new code that happened on `develop` after you started testing. Essentially this is identical to making a dedicated `release` branch, but without actually naming it. The same goes for a hotfix. Typically hotfixes are a minor change in a single commit. I would recommend branching off of master into some branch, but it doesn't have to be called `hotfix`; any name will do. Then PR that branch into `master` and merge `master` back into `develop` when done, or, as Git Flow points out, if a `release` branch already exists, then merge `master` back into `release` instead of `develop` (though you could also merge `release` back to `develop` too if you want that fix there sooner).

**Side Side note:** the most common complaint I hear about Git Flow is that it is unnecessarily complex. I find the complexity to be absolutely necessary for some organizations, and of course not necessary for others. You can pick and choose which parts of it you wish to use, and adjust when necessary. If you haven't needed `release` branches yet that's great- just tweak your workflow to merge in just the commit ID from `develop` into `master` when you release. But if you find you need a bugfix against that commit ID, maybe then you could create a `release` branch on the fly. This was you could get by without dedicated `release` branches *most* of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Following the git-flow image below :
[image]

you can go from master to develop if you need to fix some issue that take a lot of time (start a big fix if you have a quick task like fix css , code styling ...).
In your case you can start a new feature and when you finish you can make merge to develop using :

- git merge
- git rebase
- git cherry-pick
  or using git-flow command:
- git flow feature finish

I hope that can help you to improve your work.