# Should I test master branch before put into production?

Tags: bitbucket, git-flow

I'm working with git flow and a doubt arouse about the **master** branch. I have development and user acceptance working on **develop** branch and when I finish the test, I merge the **develop** with **master** branch and put into production. My question is if something goes wrong after this merge with **master** branch, I will not have tested it. What should I do to have the **master** branch tested? How to ensure that the **master** is not broken? Is there any pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr:** No, you already tested it.

**Details:**

In a properly implemented Git-Flow strategy, anything you merge into `master` should be fully ahead of `master` <sup>1</sup>, so you would never need to test what you'll get after merging into `master`, as it will be the identical state before and after the merge. (And presumably you have fully tested the branch *before* merging into `master`!) The reason this is true is that when `hotfix` branches are merged into `master`, they should be immediately merged back down into `develop` too (or into a `release` branch if one currently exists). This means there should never be any code that is *only* on `master` and not yet in the branch you're about to merge into `master`. As [documented by Git Flow](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/#finishing-a-hotfix-branch) regarding completing hotfix branches:

> When finished, the bugfix needs to be merged back into `master`, but also needs to be merged back into `develop`, in order to safeguard that the bugfix is included in the next release as well. This is completely similar to how release branches are finished.

And also,

> The one exception to the rule here is that, **when a release branch currently exists, the hotfix changes need to be merged into that release branch, instead of `develop`**.

**Side Note:** You mentioned that you are merging `develop` directly into `master`, and you can do that if it's working for you, but I just want to point out that typically in Git Flow you use a `release` branch instead. Doing so enables simultaneous development on `develop` while you are hardening a release as it awaits deployment. Here's a [question that discusses this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67089993/184546), and my answer there provides some tips for how to avoid creating `release` branches in Git Flow, if you normally don't need them.

---

<sup>1</sup> In Git we oftentimes say that one branch is "fully ahead" of another branch when the first branch can reach the tip commit of the second branch. For example, `develop` is ahead of `master` if the tip commit of `master` is in the history of the `develop` branch. In this case however what we actually mean is that all commits with state changes in `master` are present on `develop`, and this distinction exists only because of the `--no-ff` requirement when merging into `master`, so it's possible that `master` might have some merge commits that don't yet exist on `develop`. Those merge commits do not contain any new state though, so we can say from a practical point of view that `develop` is fully ahead of `master`.

From a purity standpoint, my personal preference is to always have every commit on `master` be present in `develop` or `release` before merging into `master`, so that we can say "fully ahead" and mean it from a commit ID standpoint as well. To achieve this, you can slightly tweak the documented Git Flow by, instead of merging `release` and `hotfix` branches back to `develop` after merging into `master`, merge `master` back down into `develop`. This achieves the identical state but also achieves the "fully ahead" meaning that we like to see in Git. It also means anytime you merge anything into `master`, you *could* do a fast forward merge, but we choose to use `--no-ff` instead to maintain a historical record of when the merge occurred, and exactly what was merged. **Using this tweak, the fact that you *could* have done a fast-forward merge is the *proof* you need that you don't have re-test `master` after the merge.**

Comment: I'll add a branch `release` between `develop` and `master`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the **master** branch changed since you forked the **develop** branch, you certainly could break **master** after merging **develop** (especially if you had to sift through merge conflicts), even if **develop** was working fine on its own. The way to make sure that **master** isn't broken after merging is to have good unit tests for master to make sure no existing functionality is broken, and then add and run additional unit tests for **develop** which test the new feature works after its merged.

Comment: Note this question is tagged with Git Flow, so your first sentence is not possible in a properly implemented Git Flow strategy. I would have agreed with your answer if this wasn't for Git Flow though. ;)